# Could non-continuous sequence of functions converge uniformly to continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If continuous sequence $ \left( f_n\left(x\right) \right)$ converges uniformly to function $f\left(x\right)$ in some interval of real numbers, than $f\left(x\right)$ must be also continuous.

But if non-continuous sequence $ \left( f_n\left(x\right) \right)$ converges uniformly to $f\left(x\right)$ , can $f\left(x\right)$ be continuous ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, take

$$f_n(x)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{cc}0&x\neq 0\\\frac{1}{n} & x=0\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Alternately, let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ if $x$ is rational and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: could non-continuous sequence of functions converge uniformly to non-continuous function ??