# A sequence of discontinuous functions that converges uniformly to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, continuity

The definition I have been given on my course for uniform convergence is that 
 A sequence of functions $f_n:D\to\mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to a function $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ if the real sequence $$||f_n - f||=\sup(|f_n-f|:x\in D)\to 0$$
I have been asked to find a sequence of discontinuous functions $f_n : [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that uniformly converges to a continuous function. I chose $$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & x=0\\
0 & x\neq0
\end{cases}$$
as my sequence and claim that it converges uniformly to the continuous (constant) function $f(x)=0$.

### Proof

Let $f_n$ and $f$ be defined as above, then $$\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert  =\left\Vert f_{n}-0\right\Vert 
 =\sup\{|f_{n}|:x\in[0,1]\}
 =|\frac{1}{n}|$$
Now let $\epsilon >0$ be given, by the Archimedean property we can find $N\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. So choose such $N$, then for all $n\geq N$ we have $$\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert =|\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon\implies\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert\to0$$ and thus, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. 
 Is this a valid proof? My only concern is having chosen a constant function to converge to.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And you could be "even more discontinuous" by letting $f_n(x)=\frac 1n$ for $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $=0$ otherwise ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could non-continuous sequence of functions converge uniformly to continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632225/could-non-continuous-sequence-of-functions-converge-uniformly-to-continuous-func)